# Teradata SQL query parsing. Identify comennts (using SQL)

Tags: sql, parsing, teradata, regexp-replace, sql-comments

Im working on teradata log analysis and faced with issue that a lot of queries have comments. Can somebody help in REGEXP_REPLACE defiinition or may be advice some other way how to do it?

So task is to remove/replace query part with (it can be in any position in sql and may repeat):

1. --text
2. /* text */

I spent a lot of time on it and stil no good results.

I tried to use REGEXP_REPLACE but faced with problems:

1. how to difine 'end of line'. for comments difiend as '--text'. Beginning -- till 'end of line'
2. how to deal with several comments in query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Findout how to do it:

`RegExp_Replace(SqlTextInfo,'[\t\r\n]|(--[^\r\n]*)|(/\*[\w\W]*?(?=\*/)\*/)')`